# Animations in Phaser JS are not playing when 'not' set to loop

Tags: javascript, html, game-development, phaser-framework

I want to create an animation that will be triggered by certain event, play once and then terminate. This code isn't doing it for me even if I tried setting `repeat: 0` and the 2nd parameter of `anims.play()` function as false/blank but it just completely stops the animation and does nothing at all.

**Animation Code**

```
this.anims.create({
        key: 'die',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', { start: 91, end: 97 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: 0
    });
```

**Trigger Code**

```
if (gameOver) {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
        player.anims.play('die',true);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you must be setting the a different animation in the `update` function or so.
Just track if the *player/sprite* is alive. if the *player/sprite* is dead, prevent starting a different animation on the *"dead"* sprite.

**Here a small Demo, showcasing this:**
*(to recreate the issue you are having, just remove the marked `if/else` - block in the `update`function)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: { default: 'arcade', },
    scene: {
        preload,
        create, 
        update
    }
}; 

var keys;
var player;
var player_is_dead = false

function preload(){
    this.load.spritesheet(
        'brawler', 
        'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', 
        { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 }
    );
}

function update(){
  let speed = 50;
  
  // remove this if statment to simulate the issue
  if(player_is_dead){
     return;
  }
  
  if(keys.left.isDown){
      player.body.setVelocityX(-speed);
      player.play('walk', true);
      player.setFlipX(false);
  } else if(keys.right.isDown){
      player.body.setVelocityX(speed);
      player.play('walk', true);
      player.setFlipX(true);
  } else {
      player.body.setVelocity(0)
      player.play('idle', true);
  }
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, [
            'A - Key move left',
            'S - Key move right',
            'SPACE - Key to kill',
            'ENTER - Key to reset'
        ])
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'walk',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'die',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 35, 36, 37 ] }),
      frameRate: 8,
    });
    
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'idle',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1
    });
  
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 70);
    player.setScale(3.5);
    
    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-SPACE', _ => {
        player_is_dead = true;
        player.play('die');
    });
    
    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-ENTER', function (event) {
        player_is_dead = false;
    });
    
    keys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        left: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A,
        right: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> This example is based of [this official demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/create-animation-from-sprite-sheet)

**Alternative solution, to start dying animation:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: { default: 'arcade', },
    scene: {
        preload,
        create, 
        update
    }
}; 

var keys;
var player;
var player_health = 5;

function preload(){
    this.load.spritesheet(
        'brawler', 
        'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', 
        { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 }
    );
}

function update(){
  let speed = 50;
   
  switch(player_health){
      case 0:
        if( !player.anims.currentAnim || player.anims.currentAnim.key != 'die'){
            player.play('die', true);
        }
        return;
  }
  
  if(keys.left.isDown){
      player.body.setVelocityX(-speed);
      player.play('walk', true);
      player.setFlipX(false);
  } else if(keys.right.isDown){
      player.body.setVelocityX(speed);
      player.play('walk', true);
      player.setFlipX(true);
  } else {
      player.body.setVelocity(0)
      player.play('idle', true);
  }
}

function create () {
    let timer
    let info  = this.add.text(10,10, '')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
    info.setText('Health: ' + player_health)

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'walk',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'die',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 35, 36, 37 ] }),
      frameRate: 8,
    });
    
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'idle',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1
    });
  
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 70);
    player.setScale(3.5);
   
    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-ENTER', function (event) {
        player_health = 5;
        info.setText('Health: ' + player_health);
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(timer_interval, 1000);
    });
    
    keys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        left: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A,
        right: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D
    });
    
    timer = setInterval(timer_interval , 1000);
    
    function timer_interval() {
        player_health--;
        info.setText('Health: ' + player_health);
        if(player_health <= 0){
             clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually I want to play die animation when the health is 0 like:
```case 0: life1.setFrame(2); life2.setFrame(2); life3.setFrame(2); player.isAlive = false; break;```
I'm using a switch-case statement to check health. This works fine when animation is triggered with some keypress.

Comment: @NikunjVashishtha it should work the same, you just have to prevent any starting of any other animation. If you are doing it with `health` you won't even need a new variable. I updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Got the problem, the idle animation below was overruling the die animation.